# Django testing rest-framework: APIRequestFactory vs APIClient

Tags: django, rest, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

Being new to testing i'm looking to test my API in Django (Django-rest-framework).

I'm setting up tests for my views, that is my API endpoints. Now looking over the documentation i can use an APIRequestFactory or a APIClient. Both seem to do the same thing.

What is the difference between those two, and why/when should i use one or the other??

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you look at the [tools and helpers for testing "standard" views in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/advanced/) you will find something very analogue, the [`TestClient`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client) and a [`RequestFactory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.RequestFactory).

> The RequestFactory shares the same API as the test client. However,
>   instead of behaving like a browser, the RequestFactory provides a way
>   to generate a request instance that can be used as the first argument
>   to any view. This means you can test a view function the same way as
>   you would test any other function – as a black box, with exactly known
>   inputs, testing for specific outputs.

The `TestClient` lets you interact with your site from the perspective of a user browsing your site (... though testing Javascript is yet another story). Many things come into play when testing your site like this (Sessions, Middlewares, URL-Routing, etc.). So these are typically more integrational tests that mimic real world interaction with your site or API.

A `RequestFactory` allows you to test you views in a very isolated manner. You can build a request and test your view without the need to setup your urls or care about things happening in middlewares etc.
So this is closer to a typical unit test.

That said, both types of tests are useful. To get a general feeling if your API works as expected I would probably start using the APIClient and use RequestFactories when it comes to more complex views. But the right mix depends a lot on your concrete application.